# Panel clock applet does not show correct time and date

Tags: 14.10, date

The Panel clock applet in Ubuntu 14.10 suddenly stopped showing the correct time and date! I tried restarting, but it does not work.

Comment: Do you have an old motherboard? possibly its battery is dead.

Comment: Yes it's old. Possible to fix it?

Comment: In most cases, when a motherboard cannot keep its set date & time after a restart or when it is being unplugged from power, the battery is dead. In most cases, you can simply replace its battery (it's a button). I would take it to a computer store to make sure you get the right one.

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so **hardware questions are off-topic here as well.** However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at hardware, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: I'm going to reopen this because, while hardware problems *are* off-topic here this could possibly be a software issue and will serve as a good pointer for future users with similar problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select *System Settings* -> *Time & Date* -> on the line at the bottom of the Time & Date window that says: *Set the time:* select *Automatically from the Internet*.
2. If that doesn't work, enter the BIOS when the computer is starting up and change the System Time and the System Date in the BIOS settings to their correct values. If the System Time and the System Date in the BIOS are repeatedly losing their correct values, this could be caused by a worn out CMOS battery.
3. If that doesn't work, you may need to replace the CMOS battery on the motherboard. The CMOS battery usually looks like a thin silver disk the size of a large coin. The model number is usually engraved on the top side of the CMOS battery.

[image]